# Application of group 4-cocycles

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

When considering group cohomology one can relate the low-degree groups to certain objects within group theory, e.g.:

- 1-cocycles are related to *crossed homomorphisms*
- 2-cocycles are related to *(central) extensions* (and projective representations)
- 3-cocycles are related to *crossed modules*

Now I was wondering if there exist any relations for higher-degree cohomology groups (especially 4)?

Comment: this seems to be about the periodic table of monoidal categories...

Comment: My interest for cocycles did indeed come from the study of monoidal $n$-categories (Dijkgraaf-Witten theory in particular). However, that side was quite clear to me and I wanted to know what the corresponding structures in group theory were.